# Asp.net MVC 3rd party widget session cookie not created

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, session-cookies, sessionid

I created a 3rd party widget that loads from JavaScript on a parent site. The widget loads from a different domain or a sub domain.

I am trying to use session Id to track users while they remain on the same tab/window/session. This always works on other sites I have created, but fails in this scenario, as the cookie is never created. This causes the session Id to be different for every request.

What do I need to do for the cookie to be created?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials server side and setting the xhr option allowCredentials client side allowed me to use cookies and the session.

Thanks,
Daniel